# Question asking rare examples of the use of SO(8) and Spin(8) triality

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I am just curious, why this question is put on hold [Physics application of $SO(8)$ and Spin(8) triality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359891/), while other questions that have broader ends (a real open list) are left open.

e.g.

[Physics Applications of Fredholm Theory:](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61241/physics-applications-of-fredholm-theory?rq=1)

[Examples of KMS states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/315259/examples-of-kms-states)

[Examples of Matrix Product State(s)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266587/examples-of-matrix-product-states?rq=1)

As far as I know, SO(8) and Spin(8) triality have not been used in physics application other than one example I give in 1+1D BDI Time-Reversal invariant Topological Superconductor and 2+1D Z2-Ising-symmetric Topological Superconductor have ℤ8 classifications (see a [related post here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61452/what-is-a-p-x-i-p-y-superconductor-relation-to-topological-superconductors/359521#359521)).

Other uses of SO(8) and Spin(8) triality may be in String Theory (but may not count as real-world physics), or possibly in disorder system or nuclear spectrum or Kondo effect (these I am just suspecting, we don't really know and it is certainly widely UN-known). They are not totally obvious examples. And there do not form a big list, if one wants to give precise use and Reference.

A side comment is that scientists and physicists learn by giving examples [don't you?]. I am not sure that what the far-insight to kill questions asking for giving meaningful examples, except that the purpose is trying to suppressing some users to use the site.

Comment: String theory certainly counts as 'real world physics' just for the record...

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but I do agree with the closure of your question: it is indeed off-topic. The good kind of off-topic though: a good, interesting question that is, unfortunately, unfit for the format of this site. Questions asking for an unlimited list of examples are always off-topic here, even if you think that, in your case, the list is actually rather short (and the topic is interesting). We try to treat all posts equally;  all questions are equal, even if some questions are more equal than others.  What's more, in principle you cannot really know whether the list is short or unlimited, so how can you be sure "your question is different"?

Also, let me stress something: questions asking for a list of examples are *always* off-topic here, even if some fly under the radar and go undetected, as is the case in the posts you link. I actually voted to close the first two links, as I agree they are essentially more broad scoped than your question (and, consequently, also off-topic). I didn't vote to close the third one: it seems to me that it is kind of specific, though I can't really say I understood what OP is asking.

Finally -- what to do with your question. You could try to ask it in the chatroom and hope someone there can help you with it. You could also reformulate it into a resource-recommendation post, though I'm not really sure that will help. A third alternative is to focus on some particular context, such as "is the triality used in [insert some specific area]". In this case, the answer is either yes or no, so it cannot possibly degenerate into a limitless list of examples (which is what we are trying to avoid here). I don't know what else you can do to get an answer. Good luck!

Comment: I would write an answer to this meta post, but you already covered most things I would have said.

Comment: p.s. I did not vote down just to clarify.

Comment: I add a new precise statement in order to make it re-opened: "I have an impression that one can use $SO(8)$ and Spin(8) triality in particular in string theory (but may not count as real-world physics) or possibly in **disorder condensed matter system** or **nuclear energy spectrum**. If that is true, could one explain how does the $SO(8)$ and Spin(8) triality come in? [Citations/References are encouraged, but some explanations are required.]"

Comment: I have modified my question and make my questions focusing on a few issues: ["Physics uses of SO(8) and Spin(8) triality"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/359891/). But I haven't heard back from any of moderators. Generally, if you understand the SO(8) and Spin(8) triality, you will know that it will be hard and very surprising to come up with any direct use in physics. And there is no way I could be more focusing than what I said (otherwise I would not ask about it).

Comment: @wonderich your question is still in the "reopen queue", and it already has 3 votes to reopen. If two more people vote to reopen it, it will automatically be reopened, regardless of what moderators think (they may close it again, but I don't think they will). The best thing you can do now is to wait for one or two more days, and hope for the best. In any case, IMHO your reformulated question is better than before but it is still asking for a list of examples, so there is a lot of room for improvement (you may leave it as is for now, and re-edit it again if reviewers vote to leave it closed).

Comment: Thanks. In my humble opinion, knowledgeable guys should know what are the bad questions to be closed. And what are not the questions to be closed. I am a researcher from Princeton University. I do not attempt to ask trivial bad questions here to embarrass myself.   (So it boils down to one's motivation to close other's questions.)