# Can I ask for an example?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I'd like to ask for an example in which the minimum energy principle is used (thermodynamics). However, I've never seen a question in which examples are required, so I got the doubt that it's not allowed to ask for examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions asking for examples are *list questions*, discussed on meta already at e.g. [Good list, bad list](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4561/50583), [May I ask a big-list question?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10823/50583), [When are questions with multiple different possible answers good?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13518/50583), [Question asking rare examples of the use of SO(8) and Spin(8) triality](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10186/50583).

Overall the question you have in mind is likely to be off-topic.